# how to match in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one for candidates and their skills, and the other for jobs and the skills  required for the job, such as the ones shown below:

CSID = candidate skill ID (PK) 
CID = candidate ID (FK) 
S_CODE = skill code (FK)

Here is the candidate_skill table

```
+------------+---------+---------+
| CSID       | CID     |  S_CODE |
+------------+---------+---------+
| 1          | 1       | 5       |
| 2          | 1       | 9       |
| 3          | 2       | 5       |
| 4          | 2       | 10      |
+------------+---------+---------+
```

SJID = skill job ID (PK) 
JID = job ID (FK) 
S_CODE = skill code (FK)

Here is the skill_job table:

```
+------------+---------+---------+
| SJID       | JID     |  S_CODE |
+------------+---------+---------+
| 12         | 50      | 5       |
| 13         | 50      | 9       |
| 14         | 51      | 1       |
| 15         | 52      | 10      |
+------------+---------+---------+
```

So in this example, the only candidate would be 1 for the job 50, since the skill codes (S_CODE) are 5 and 9 for both, but i also would like candidate 2 to be a match to 52, since it has the required job skill and an extra one.
I have tried several ways to match the job and candidate but I'm failing, an example of such a way is the code below:

```
    SELECT * , COUNT(skill_job.S_CODE) AS cnt FROM candidate_skill,
 skill_job WHERE candidate_skill.S_CODE = skill_job.S_CODE HAVING (cnt >=2)
```

the problem is, that only limits the candidate found to one and if i remove the COUNT clause, it lists all candidates that match with only one skill so candidate 2 would also be matched to the job 50.

Here is the mysql code for the tables from phpmyadmin:

```
    -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.4.5
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Jul 16, 2012 at 09:27 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.16
-- PHP Version: 5.3.8

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `employment`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `candidate`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `candidate` (
  `CID` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `dob` date NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `phone_num` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `regdate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `acc_type` enum('c','s') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'c',
  `emailactivate` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cv_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `cv` blob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='// this is the table for the candidates' AUTO_INCREMENT=175 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `candidate`
--

INSERT INTO `candidate` (`CID`, `title`, `fname`, `lname`, `dob`, `email`, `address`, `city`, `postcode`, `phone_num`, `username`, `password`, `regdate`, `acc_type`, `emailactivate`, `cv_name`, `cv`) VALUES
(128, 'Mr', 'clement', 'Chilingulo', '0000-00-00', 'chlngl@yahoo.com', '28 oakfield Road', 'london', 'E6 1LW', '07771611873', 'casante', 'b59c67bf196a4758191e42f76670ceba', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'c', '0', '', '');
INSERT INTO `candidate` (`CID`, `title`, `fname`, `lname`, `dob`, `email`, `address`, `city`, `postcode`, `phone_num`, `username`, `password`, `regdate`, `acc_type`, `emailactivate`, `cv_name`, `cv`) VALUES
(134, 'Mr', 'rverv', 'revrb', '0000-00-00', 'tdbsdrt', 'trsbrtd', 'trbtrtrb', 'tbrfbgrts', 'trfbtrgbrfg', 'clement', 'b59c67bf196a4758191e42f76670ceba', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 's', '0', '', '');
INSERT INTO `candidate` (`CID`, `title`, `fname`, `lname`, `dob`, `email`, `address`, `city`, `postcode`, `phone_num`, `username`, `password`, `regdate`, `acc_type`, `emailactivate`, `cv_name`, `cv`) VALUES
(165, 'Mr', 'oinInINOioni', 'ioin', '0000-00-00', 'inioimn', 'in', 'oin', 'oni', 'io', 'k', '7b8b965ad4bca0e41ab51de7b31363a1', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'c', '0', '', ''),
(166, 'Mr', 'pjINoNlkinoinoi', 'ino', '0000-00-00', 'oimpnponi', 'inoi', 'no', 'nj', 'nio', 'nio', 'eb5bc837d01b911029ae378e8a1c9f5d', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'c', '0', '', ''),
(167, 'Mr', 'vrae', 'ergvaer', '0000-00-00', 'aerbg', 'aergvera', 'aergvrea', 'aergvear', 'aergarev', 'grebvarvf', '609c1b136ec8d0d2dfdf9a2105fb605f', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'c', '0', '', ''),
(168, 'Mr', 'vrae', 'ergvaer', '0000-00-00', 'aerbg', 'aergvera', 'aergvrea', 'aergvear', 'aergarev', 'grebvarvf', '609c1b136ec8d0d2dfdf9a2105fb605f', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'c', '0', '', ''),
(169, 'Mr', 'ubp', 'bu', '0000-00-00', 'ubip', ';ub', 'ubi', 'ubo', 'buo', 'ubiipbu', '9f44ce1389a3e7372834ed730b559a5e', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'c', '0', '', ''),
(170, 'Mr', 'rvev', 'ferhbgetb', '0000-00-00', 'tsbtrb', 'trbstrb', 'trbsfb ', 'stb stb', 'vvfs', 'csdcdsvarewdcv', 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'c', '0', '', ''),
(171, 'Mr', 'rvev', 'ferhbgetb', '0000-00-00', 'tsbtrb', 'trbstrb', 'trbsfb ', 'stb stb', 'vvfs', 'csdcdsvarewdcv', 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'c', '0', '', ''),
(172, '', '', '', '0000-00-00', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'c', '0', '', ''),
(173, '', 'dds', 'vrv av', '0000-00-00', 'rvear', 'vreverav', 'rvedfsdv', 'frvdvf', 'fveavd', 'vdrareavdv', '84c71ac76340092398a1ed4bc7d6fe19', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'c', '0', '', ''),
(174, '', 'dds', 'vrv av', '0000-00-00', 'rvedwear', 'vreverav', 'rvedfsdv', 'frvdvf', 'fveavd', 'vdraredfcavdv', 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'c', '0', '', '');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `candidate_skill`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `candidate_skill` (
  `CSID` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CID` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `S_CODE` int(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CSID`),
  KEY `CID` (`CID`),
  KEY `S_CODE` (`S_CODE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='//match candidate and skill' AUTO_INCREMENT=131 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `candidate_skill`
--

INSERT INTO `candidate_skill` (`CSID`, `CID`, `S_CODE`) VALUES
(114, 134, 2),
(116, 134, 9),
(121, 134, 5),
(126, 128, 1);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `job`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `job` (
  `JID` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `job_title` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `job_desc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `end_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`JID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='// this is the table for the job vacancies' AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `job`
--

INSERT INTO `job` (`JID`, `job_title`, `job_desc`, `start_date`, `end_date`) VALUES
(1, 'engineer', ' fix engineering ish that is messed ', '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00'),
(5, 'pilot', '', '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00'),
(8, 'Charity Helper', ' ', '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00'),
(9, 'accountant', '  ', '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `skill`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `skill` (
  `S_CODE` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '// this is the skill primary key',
  `skill_name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `skill_desc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`S_CODE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `skill`
--

INSERT INTO `skill` (`S_CODE`, `skill_name`, `skill_desc`) VALUES
(1, 'speaking', 'English is your first language'),
(2, '  writing', 'You can write English very well'),
(3, ' public', ''),
(5, 'initiative', ''),
(6, 'interviewing', ''),
(7, 'negotiating', ''),
(8, 'leading', ''),
(9, '  energy', ''),
(10, ' organisation', '');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `skill_job`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `skill_job` (
  `SJID` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `JID` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `S_CODE` int(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SJID`),
  KEY `S_CODE` (`S_CODE`),
  KEY `JID` (`JID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=106 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `skill_job`
--

INSERT INTO `skill_job` (`SJID`, `JID`, `S_CODE`) VALUES
(91, 5, 2),
(94, 5, 5),
(95, 5, 9),
(98, 1, 1),
(102, 1, 8),
(105, 8, 8);

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `candidate_skill`
--
ALTER TABLE `candidate_skill`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `candidate_skill_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`CID`) REFERENCES `candidate` (`CID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `candidate_skill_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`S_CODE`) REFERENCES `skill` (`S_CODE`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `skill_job`
--
ALTER TABLE `skill_job`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `skill_job_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`JID`) REFERENCES `job` (`JID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `skill_job_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`S_CODE`) REFERENCES `skill` (`S_CODE`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: It isn't very obvious as to what CSID, CID, S_CODE, SJID, and JID stand for.

Comment: In the first table, the last row's 'csid' is 3, is that accurate? Not understanding columns as well.

Comment: Can you stick an SQL script full of insert queries so we can get a feel for these tables without squinting at them?

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS i'll add the script from my db, it contains 5 tables

Comment: Can you include insert statements? Use something like MySQL workbench, or PHPmyAdmin It can do that for you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double negation is your friend (though I don't know MySQL well enough to tell whether it supports it):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CS.CID, SJ.JID
FROM CANDIDATE_SKILL CS
JOIN SKILL_JOB SJ ON CS.S_CODE = SJ.S_CODE
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                 FROM SKILL_JOB SJ2
                 WHERE SJ.JID = SJ2.JID
                   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                                  FROM CANDIDATE_SKILL CS2
                                  WHERE CS.CID = CS2.CID
                                    AND SJ2.S_CODE = CS2.S_CODE))
```

A 'human translation' of this is to say that there should not exists any skill required for the job that the candidate doesn't have.

Comment: you might not know MySQL well but I assure you, you are awesome, the code worked wonderfully

Comment: Yeah that was a great effort, Set :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you'll need to use an [INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) to combine your two tables and then compare their row values.

Comment: `FROM candidate_skill,skill_job` is the same as an INNER JOIN.

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius: Yes it is. "INNER JOIN and , (comma) are semantically equivalent in the absence of a join condition" docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: @Rocket Interesting, I did not know this!  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: It just is completely impossible :) With INNER you join on something. With comma, there is no need to provide what you join on, so you can get Decart's matrix. Try getting Decart's matrix with INNER.

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius: When you use the comma, you need to add the join criteria in the WHERE.  `SELECT a,b FROM a,b WHERE a.id=b.id`

Comment: You DO NOT NEED to add the join criteria.

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius: True, you don't *need* to :-P

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this..

```
SELECT
   CID
FROM 
   candidate_skill
WHERE
   S_CODE IN (
               SELECT S_CODE FROM skill_jobs where JID = 52 
             )
GROUP BY CID
```

CORRECTION: Previous query will fail to match all required S_CODE

```
SELECT
   CID, COUNT(CSID) as cnt
FROM 
   candidate_skill
INNER JOIN skill_jobs 
WHERE
   S_CODE IN (
               SELECT S_CODE FROM skill_jobs where JID = 52 
             )
GROUP BY CID 
HAVING cnt = (
               SELECT count(*) from skill_jobs where JID = 52
             )
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a bit more complicated JOIN, and I see no easy way of simultaneously answering your request and the obvious ones "How is candidate X matched for job Y?" and "HOW MUCH does candidate X fit job Y?".

Anyway, here goes.

```
SELECT candidate_skill.CID, skill_job.JID, COUNT(*) AS has, sjtot.needed
    FROM skill_job JOIN candidate_skill ON (candidate_skill.S_CODE = skill_job.S_CODE)
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT JID, COUNT(*) AS needed FROM skill_job GROUP BY JID ) AS sjtot
        ON ( skill_job.JID = sjtot.JID )
GROUP BY CID, JID
HAVING has >= needed;
```

In practice I first group the required skills on skill_job, and this tells me that job 50 requires two skills.

Armed with this, I LEFT JOIN required and candidate skills; some candidates will join on all skills, some won't. It is then just a matter of counting how many do match.

```
+------+------+-----+--------+
| CID  | JID  | has | needed |
+------+------+-----+--------+
|    1 |   50 |   2 |      2 |
|    2 |   52 |   1 |      1 |
+------+------+-----+--------+
```

On second thought, required skill level and offered skill levels might be selected, and CASE WHEN used to extract a match (1 if offered >= required, offered/required otherwise). The average of the resulting values might then be used as a "skill match" index.

As for the "How is X matched for Y?" question, once you know that candidate CID 1 is good for job JID 50, you can run a LEFT JOIN between the candidates and the jobs. You already know that whatever the jobs asks, the candidate has, but this way you retrieve what unasked-for skills the candidate has, and the other relevant values as well.

A nested query joining the query above and this last one would perhaps tell you everything in one fell swoop, but it would be a costly swoop, I think :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about cross-dbms support, you can use mysql specific group_concat to reduce the two s_code sets to strings, one per candidate/job and just compare them like this:

```
select * from 
(select cs.cid, group_concat(cs.s_code order by cs.s_code) skills 
    from candidate_skill cs group by cs.cid) cs, 
(select sj.jid, group_concat(sj.s_code order by sj.s_code) skills 
    from skill_job sj group by sj.jid) sj
where sj.skills = cs.skills
```

Be aware of that when your tables grown the the final where will be slower and slower and you can't create indexes on the group_concat() created fields.